# How to sup up rows within a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, sum

I have a dictionary:

```py
{
"account": "x*", 'amount': 300, 'day': 3, 'month': 'June',
"account": "y*", 'amount': 550, 'day': 9, 'month': 'May',
"account": 'z*', 'amount': -200, 'day': 21, 'month': 'June'
"account" : "g", "amount" : 80" "day" : 10" month" : "May"
}
```

How do I find the total amount for each month June and May separately?

```py
dictionary= sum(d["amount"] for d in my_dict)
```

Comment: that's not a valid python dict, just so you're not surprised when the interpreter doesn't like it.

Comment: This can't be stored in one dictionary, you need a list of dictionaries or something similar

Comment: there's no "rows" in dictionary. You're confusing it with some other data structure.

Comment: I'm afraid at this point you're leaving too much for us to decipher. Please post a bit of code that actually is valid python, and creates your `my_dict`. Neither code fragments you posted work in Python.

Comment: I found the total for both months together, how do I do it for seperate Months?

Comment: Even without the many typos, I can't understand how this would return anything but the amount for May, since all previous values for the same key are overwritten!

Answer (score 1):

You can filter which elements to sum, by adding an `if` statement at the end of the one-liner `for-loop`:

```
sum(d['amount'] for d in my_dict if d['month'] == month)
```

Then, we can wrap this line of code inside a small function to compute the results for May and June:

```
my_dict = [{'account': 'x*', 'amount':  300, 'day':  3, 'month': 'June'},
           {'account': 'y*', 'amount':  550, 'day':  9, 'month': 'May' },
           {'account': 'z*', 'amount': -200, 'day': 21, 'month': 'June'},
           {'account': 'g' , 'amount':   80, 'day': 10, 'month': 'May' }]


get_sum  = lambda my_dict, month: sum(d['amount'] for d in my_dict if d['month'] == month)
sum_June = get_sum(my_dict, 'June')
sum_May  = get_sum(my_dict, 'May' )

print('sum_June:', sum_June)
# sum_June: 100

print('sum_May :', sum_May)
# sum_May : 630
```

---

PS. Initially, the dictionary `my_dict` was over-writting data, because everything was stored in the same object. In the code above, `my_dict` is split into a list with multiple rows to avoid this issue. Please consider this methodology to store data in your project - it is very common.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to run that and in the cosole it is said "NameError: name 'month' is not defined".

Comment: Hi @Litriceee, I think your definition of `my_dict` is over-writting data because everything is stored inside the same dictionary. Please copy-past my entire code to your console, thanks. (you need to define `my_dict` using multiple rows in a list)